# How do I combine many clipping areas in html5 2d canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, 2d, clipping, html2canvas

I want to draw an area with multi-clipping areas.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

I write a drawing example: http://jsfiddle.net/younyzhU/zR9hg/1/

The total area should be the four `green` area + the center white rectangle.

From the basic tutorial, I know Drawing a cliping Plane is like drawing others things.

1. Create a clipping region
2. context.clip()

However, create a clipping region, we have multi-region, how to combine, any suggestion?
thanks.

Below is some code:

```
  ctx.save();   // save the context so we don't mess up others
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();  // restore context to what it was on entry
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";//Color for four surrounded area.
    ctx.save(); // save the context so we don't mess up others
    ctx.beginPath();
    r = Math.sqrt((this.h/2)*(this.h/2) + 16 *this.w * this.w);
    thea = Math.atan(this.h/this.w/8);
    ctx.arc(this.x + this.w*4, this.y + this.h/2, r , Math.PI - thea,  Math.PI+thea, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    //ctx.clip();
    ctx.restore();  // restore context to what it was on entry

    ctx.save(); // save the context so we don't mess up others
    ctx.beginPath();
    r = Math.sqrt((this.h/2)*(this.h/2) + 16 *this.w * this.w);
    thea = Math.atan(this.h/this.w/8);
    ctx.arc(this.x- this.w*3, this.y + this.h/2, r , -thea,  thea, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    //ctx.clip();
    ctx.restore();  // restore context to what it was on entry

    ctx.save(); // save the context so we don't mess up others
    ctx.beginPath();
    r = Math.sqrt((this.w/2)*(this.w/2) + 16 * this.h * this.h);
    thea = Math.atan(this.w/this.h/8);
    ctx.arc(this.x + this.w/2, this.y + 4 * this.h, r , Math.PI*3/2-thea,  Math.PI*3/2 + thea, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();  // restore context to what it was on entry
    ctx.save(); // save the context so we don't mess up others
    ctx.beginPath();

    r = Math.sqrt((this.w/2)*(this.w/2) + 16*this.h*this.h);
    thea = Math.atan(this.w/this.h/8);
    ctx.arc(this.x + this.w/2, this.y-3*this.h , r , Math.PI/2-thea,  Math.PI/2 + thea, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();  // restore context to what it was on entry
    ctx.save();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clipping path is actually a path.

This means if you draw all 4 of your closed arcs in one path, then you can clip with that multi-shape path.

You can combine your paths by doing 1 `beginPath` command before the arcs instead of a `beginPath` before every arc.

The result is a single path that looks like this which you can use as a clipping path:

[image]

For example, this is how that clipping path can be used to contain an image of diagonal stripes:

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LYR3E/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/rainbowDiagonal.jpg";
    function start(){

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fill();

        draw();
    }

    function draw(){
        var x=50;
        var y=50;
        var w=200;
        var h=200;

        ctx.save();

        ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";//Color for four surrounded area.

        ctx.beginPath();

        r = Math.sqrt((h/2)*(h/2) + 16 *w * w);
        thea = Math.atan(h/w/8);
        ctx.arc(x + w*4, y + h/2, r , Math.PI - thea,  Math.PI+thea, false);
        ctx.closePath();

        r = Math.sqrt((h/2)*(h/2) + 16 *w * w);
        thea = Math.atan(h/w/8);
        ctx.arc(x- w*3, y + h/2, r , -thea,  thea, false);
        ctx.closePath();

        r = Math.sqrt((w/2)*(w/2) + 16 * h * h);
        thea = Math.atan(w/h/8);
        ctx.arc(x + w/2, y + 4 * h, r , Math.PI*3/2-thea,  Math.PI*3/2 + thea, false);
        ctx.closePath();

        r = Math.sqrt((w/2)*(w/2) + 16*h*h);
        thea = Math.atan(w/h/8);
        ctx.arc(x + w/2, y-3*h , r , Math.PI/2-thea,  Math.PI/2 + thea, false);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.clip();

        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

        ctx.restore();

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Create a clipping region is just combine with one path? Ok, I thought I can use multi-path combined. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, a clipping path is always just a single path.  But you can combine as many drawing commands as you need inside that single path. ;-)